# Closure of convex hull is weakly compact

Tags: functional-analysis

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$. Set $f_N = N^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{n=1}^N e_n$  for all $N\geq 1$ show that:

a) $e_n\rightarrow 0$ weakly, as $n\rightarrow \infty$

b) $f_N\rightarrow 0$ weakly, as $N\rightarrow\infty$, while $\norm{f_N}=1$ for all $N\geq 1$.

Let $K$ be the norm closure of $co\{f_N:N\geq 1\}$

c) Argue that $K$ is weakly compact, and that $0\in K$

I have showed a) and b) but I am a little stock on c) Hope you can help me out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hilbert spaces are reflexive and any weakly closed bounded sets in them  are weakly compact. [This is a corollary of Banach - Alaoglu Theorem].  Also the weak closure of a convex set is same as its norm closure. It follows that $K$ is weakly closed and bounded, hence weakly compact. Since $0$ is in the weak closure of $\{f_n:n \geq1\}$ (and hence of it convex hull) it is also in the norm closure of this convex hull. So $0 \in K$.

Comment: Can you show me how to find the extreme point in this set?